# Windows server as a domain controller but not DHCP and DNS server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I want to integrate domain in my company. My colleague says he don't want windows server because it must become everything (DC, DHCP and DNS server). My question is can you have Widows Server only as a domain controller and not DHCP and DNS server?

Comment: `I want to integrate domain in my company. My colleague says he don't want windows server because it must become everything (DC, DHCP and DNS server).` - Your colleague is wrong. `My question is can you have Widows Server only as a domain controller and not DHCP and DNS server?` - Yes, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install and configure the Active Directory Domain Services without installing the DNS role.

However, if you want to use your own DNS infrastructure, you will have to manually configure it according to the documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/creating-a-dns-infrastructure-design

DHCP is a completely separated role and has noting to do with AD so you can use another DHCP server if you want.